# Looking for ways to make Drools / Optaplanner faster

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I am working on a capstone project using    `Optaplanner 6.2.0.CR4`    and `Drools` to incrementally score the solution. The problem is pretty similar to `Optaplanner's Nurse Rostering example`, with a little added complexity. I was wondering if there were any common pitfalls that can slow down Drools that I could look for in my code. The solver runs the `Construction Phase` pretty quickly, but hits a wall when it gets to the `local search phase`. Drools is inserting a lot of additional stuff like counting work days per pay period, blocks of specific duration free time per pay period, etc and I'm thinking the way I wrote the rules might be the problem.

Comment: "...common pitfalls that can slow down Drools..." The possibilities are legion.

Comment: I am pretty new to drools, all I'm really doing is inserting facts, which in this case are premade java classes, that are counted up for each planning entity and then rules activate and adjust the score. The only functions I'm really using is Number() from accumulate and conditional statements

Comment: Since everybody is just "inserting facts", and without particularly disturbing effects, the slowdown must be due to something else. - Mind you, we can discuss this at this level for days to come, but if you want some real help you'll have to come clean.

Comment: Despite your doubt, that is literally all I am doing. Thank you for your constructive comments. Anyone else have any input?

Comment: Sigh. Why don't you post your rules?

Comment: What's your "average score calculation count per second"? See docs about logging: it's in the last log statement on info level. That should be above 1000, preferably around 5000 to 20 000 with drools calculation. Note that you can even go much higher with Java Incremental calculation but that's a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See docs ["Score performance tricks"](http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#scoreCalculationPerformanceTricks). Especially keep an eye out on your "average score calculation count per second". It should be above `1000`, preferably above `10000`.

**Use [the OptaPlanner benchmarker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JpcPEieU3Cg).** It will be your best friend in this endevour, thrust me :)

Note: Ask yourself: What do you mean with "faster"? Do you want better results in the same time? Do you want the same results faster? And/Or do you want to scale out more? There might be trade-off choices to make there - use the OptaPlanner Benchmarker to see the pure gains on all 3 fronts, but also to visualize trade-offs between those 3 fronts.